# How common are shareholders' clubs and 'fidelity bonuses'?

Tags: shares

I was wondering:

- How common are shareholders' clubs outside France? In France, at least a dozen of the CAC 40 companies have such clubs, where they offer various advantages like museum / concert tickets, price reductions on their shops, etc. (e.g. BNP Paribas, LVMH...)
- Similarly, how common are 'fidelity bonuses', which are bonus dividends (often +10% on normal dividends) that you can earn if you hold the shares in your name for a certain amount of time (e.g. >= 2 years).

As a sidenote, such advantages are a significant plus for me, and one of the reasons why I avoid French ETFs.

Comment: I have never heard of such a thing so I would assume they're far less common in Germany and the US, but I can't know for sure.